# Check string in dictionary for keywords from 2 separate lists

Tags: python, string, list, loops, dictionary

I have a dictionary with keys as ID and values as string. I also have two separate lists with keywords. 
I need to filter out all keys in the dictionary, the values of which have atleast one keyword from list 1 and atleast one keyword from list 2. 
I am confused how to go about this. please help.

So far, this is what I have:

```
# code loads all data from al.csv into a dictionary where the key is column 1 which is tweet ID and value is the the whole row including tweet ID.
reader = csv.reader(open('al.csv', 'r'))
overallDict = {}
for rows in reader:
    k = rows[0]
    v = rows[0] + ',' + rows[1] + ',' + rows[2] + ',' + rows[3] + ',' + rows[4] + ',' + rows[5] + ',' + rows[6] + ',' + rows[7] + ',' + rows[8] + ',' + rows[9]
    overallDict[k] = v

# The following lines of code loop loads keywords list
with open('slangNames.txt') as f:
    slangs = f.readlines()

# To strip new-line and prepare data into finished keywords list
strippedSlangs = []
for elements in slangs:
    elements = elements.strip()
    strippedSlangs.append(elements)

# The following lines of code loop loads risks list
with open('riskNames.txt') as f:
    risks = f.readlines()

# To strip new-line and prepare data into finished risks list
strippedRisks = []
for things in risks:
    things = things.strip()
    strippedRisks.append(things)
```

Say List1 = [opium, christmas, weed]
and List2 = [drug, harmful, bad]
and Dictionary = {213432:'opium is harmful for health', 321234:'christmas is good', 543678:'weed is bad'}

the desired output needs to be the list:
Output: [213432, 543678] because these two corresponding tweets contain atleast one value from list1 and one from list2.

Comment: Could you provide some actual test data for the dict and the two lists? We do not have those files you read... Also, try `','.join(rows)`

Comment: Please provide some sample input and output?, Your given code doesn't helps much in understanding the problem.

Comment: I apologize. Say List1 = [opium, christmas, weed] and List2 = [drug, harmful, bad] and Dictionary = {213432:'opium is harmful for health', 321234:'christmas is good', 543678:'weed is bad'}

the desired output needs to be the list: Output: [213432, 543678] because these two corresponding tweets contain atleast one value from list1 and one from list2.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I had to rewrite your code to figure out more easily what it was doing:

```
strippedRisks = set()
strippedSlangs = set()
overallDict = {}

with open('al.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
       overallDict[row[0]] = ",".join(row[1:])

with open('slangNames.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        elements = line.strip()
        strippedSlangs.add(elements)

with open('riskNames.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        things = line.strip()
        strippedRisks.add(things)
```

Okay. You want to know which keys in your dictionary have values in each of the lists it sounds like? In other words, you want to know which `values` of the dictionary have a word that is disallowed.

You can probably do something like this:

```
for key, value in overallDict.items():
  if set(value.split(',')).intersection(strippedSlangs):
     # some words appear in strippedSlangs
  elif set(value.split(',')).intersection(strippedRisks)
     # some words appear in strippedRisks
```

However, now that I see what you want to do, I'd just use sets from the beginning and build the not-permitted words first:

```
strippedRisks = set()
strippedSlangs = set()
overallDict = {}

with open('slangNames.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        elements = line.strip()
        strippedSlangs.add(elements)

with open('riskNames.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        things = line.strip()
        strippedRisks.add(things)

with open('al.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        values = set(row[1:])
        if strippredRisks.intersection(values) and strippedSlangs.intersection(values):
            # Words in both bad-word lists. Do we skip these or save them?
            pass
        else:
            overallDict[row[0]] = values
```

I *believe* that's what you're trying to accomplish, but I'm not totally sure.

Comment: thank you very much for replying. in the lines: for row in reader:
        values = set(row[1:])
        if strippredRisks.intersection(values) or strippedSlangs.intersection(values):
            pass
        else:
            overallDict[row[0]] = values, should we not use AND instead of OR? I ask because atleast one term from risks and atleast one term from slangs have to be there in the dictionary value.